# Problems with gnuplot in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, gnuplot

I want to represent information in a graphic using gnuplot but I have a problem because gnuplot send me an error when I execute it.
I put the code table:

*Tablas.txt*

```
100,69.62,71.5649,10.04,10.1743
105,74.94,78.6931,10.36,10.8261
110,95.72,86.1286,11.12,11.4779
115,90.76,93.8714,11.88,12.1298
120,96.42,101.922,12.62,12.7816
125,113.96,110.279,12.84,13.4334
130,120.08,118.944,13.46,14.0852
135,125.12,127.916,13.94,14.737
140,139.02,137.196,18.74,15.3889
145,161.12,146.782,16.3,16.0407
150,157.22,156.677,18.46,16.6925
155,161.4,166.878,17.8,17.3443
160,169.7,177.387,20.28,17.9962
165,199.06,188.203,19.28,18.648
170,190.44,199.327,18.36,19.2998
175,201.86,210.758,18.92,19.9516
180,237.18,222.496,19.9,20.6034
185,228.98,234.542,20.64,21.2553
190,236.7,246.894,21.74,21.9071
195,265.32,259.555,22.04,22.5589
200,259.92,272.522,22.3,23.2107
205,310.02,285.797,23.48,23.8626
210,287.96,299.38,25.04,24.5144
215,312.38,313.269,24.22,25.1662
220,314.82,327.466,24.72,25.818
225,343.7,341.97,25.42,26.4698
230,343.18,356.782,25.8,27.1217
235,388.08,371.901,26.5,27.7735
240,395.6,387.327,30.5,28.4253
245,392.02,403.061,31.36,29.0771
250,431.7,419.102,31.92,29.729
255,445.42,435.45,30.22,30.3808
260,439.88,452.106,31.16,31.0326
265,475.14,469.069,30.54,31.6844
270,493.12,486.339,31.38,32.3362
275,507.32,503.917,33,32.9881
280,519.48,521.802,33.72,33.6399
285,529.14,539.994,33.5,34.2917
290,561.02,558.494,34.12,34.9435
295,578.88,577.301,35.82,35.5954
300,592.08,596.416,38.2,36.2472
```

This is my code of the script of gnuplot. I execute it using:

*ejemplo_gnuplot.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << _end_ | gnuplot
set terminal postscript eps color
set output "grafico.eps"
set key right bottom
set xlabel "Etiqueta eje X"
set ylabel "Etiqueta Eje Y"
plot 'tablas.txt' using 1:2 t "Datos columna 2 frente a 1" w l,     'tablas.txt' using 1:3 t "Datos columna 3 frente a 1" w l, 'tablas.txt' using 1:5 t "Datos columna 5 frente a 1" w l, 'tablas.txt' using 1:6 t "Datos columna 6 frente a 1" w l 
_end_
```

This is the output of the execution of the script

*ejecutar script*

```
./ejemplo_gnuplot.sh 
         line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
         line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
         line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
         line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

gnuplot> plot 'tablas.txt' using 1:2 t "Datos columna 2 frente a 1" w l, 'tablas.txt' using 1:3 t "Datos columna 3 frente a 1" w l, 'tablas.txt' using 1:5 t "Datos columna 5 frente a 1" w l, 'tablas.txt' using 1:6 t "Datos columna 6 frente a 1" w l 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^
         line 0: x range is invalid
```

Can anybody help me to solve the problem, pls?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like your data is comma-separated, so you need `set datafile separator ","`.

Comment: Check the data file name tables.txt vs Tablas.txt as it is case sensitive.

Comment: I have the file named by tablas.txt I had a mistake writing it in StackOverflow. Thanks